# How does self attention help in deciding references

Tags: reference, resolve, self-attention

Consider the two sentences: "The animal did not cross the road because it was too tired" and "The animal did not cross the road because it was too crowded".  How does the self attention mechanism determine that in the first case "it" refers to "animal" and in the second case to "road"?